# Can we count the number of code review comments in gerrit?

Tags: gerrit

I have a task where I need to fetch number of code review comments made for a particular gerrit review commit. Then later I need to apply filters on EPIC ID, BUC ID and count review comments made on each EPIC/BUC etc.

Is there any way to know or fetch the review comments from gerrit? And then count the number of comments?

Comment: Tried below query as well but it does not return anything on code-review comments :
ssh -p 29418 gerrit.epk.ericsson.se gerrit query --format=JSON project:onm/onm --comments --patch-sets --files

Answer (score 3):

You can use REST to get the comments in a change:

```
curl -s --request GET https://GERRIT-SERVER/a/changes/CHANGE-NUMBER/comments
```

Or in a specific patchset:

```
curl -s --request GET https://GERRIT-SERVER/a/changes/CHANGE-NUMBER/revisions/PATCHSET-NUMBER/comments
```

Then you can process the output using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/).

For example, use this:

```
curl -s --request GET https://GERRIT-SERVER/a/changes/CHANGE-NUMBER/revisions/PATCHSET-NUMBER/comments | sed 1d | jq --raw-output ".[][] | {Updated: .updated, Message: .message}"
```

To get the following:

```
{
  "Updated": "2016-10-17 16:27:54.000000000",
  "Message": "COMMENT-1"
}
{
  "Updated": "2016-10-17 16:30:22.000000000",
  "Message": "COMMENT-2"
}
```

Or use this:

```
curl -s --request GET https://GERRIT-SERVER/a/changes/CHANGE-NUMBER/revisions/PATCHSET-NUMBER/comments | sed 1d | jq --raw-output ".[][].id" | wc -l
```

To get the number of comments:

```
2
```